# Using jQuery 'this' to target 1 of the li items

Tags: jquery, this

I have multiple li elements and I want a toggleFade to happen only on the li that I hover over. At the moment the code below will target all of them.

I know I need to add 'this' in there somewhere but everything I have tried doesn't work.

Here is my offending jQuery code:

```
$('li.featuredItem').hover(function() {
    $('li.featuredItem figcaption').fadeToggle('400');
});
```

Thanks, Jack

Comment: Try this:  $('li.featuredItem').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeToggle('400');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li.featuredItem').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('figcaption').fadeToggle('400');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)`,which referes to the current `element`,wrapped in a `jQuery object`.

```
$('li.featuredItem').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeToggle('400');
});
```

Comment: slight improvement: `this` refers to the current element (`$(this)` refers to the current element "wrapped in a jQuery object")

Comment: @RussCam Oops,Seriously I missed it.Thanks :)

Comment: Because I had another element hidden, I needed to target the following element on hover (i.e. hover over li then fadeToggle the next figcaption). The answer below solved my question. Thanks for the input though.